# Terminal keystrokes confusion

Tags: terminal, emacs, tmux, urxvt, keystrokes

## #1

`tmux` ignores some keystrokes:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F*</kbd>

## #2

Something similar happens in virtual consoles (even without `tmux`) with the difference that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> behaves the same.

## #3

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> pops up the help page in `emacs -nw` but this seems to be a known issue (that I can't solve).

---

I'm sorry to put so many questions in one but I guess it's all about the `TERM` variable (with values: `linux`, `screen`, `rxvt-unicode`). I'd like to setup the whole thing so that `urxvt` and the virtual consoles behaves the same with or without `tmux`. Could someone make some light on the whole issue?

**Note:** I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> followed by the keystroke to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Within Emacs you can use `C-h k` to find out what Emacs thinks about a certain key, e.g. `C-h k C-F1`. If that doesn't work, e.g. because C-BACKSPACE is interpreted as C-h you could always fall back to `C-h l` which lists the last key strokes: Press the keys in question and fire `C-h l` to see what Emacs has received.

Once you've found out what your keys map to in Emacs you could bind them to the function you like, e.g.

```
 (global-set-key [(meta d)] 'kill-word)
```

Comment: Emacs receives `C-h` whenever I press `C-BACKSPACE`.